# TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'Node'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, rich-text-editor, slatejs

I'm trying coding follow this :

https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate/blob/main/site/examples/hovering-toolbar.tsx

IDE tips:

**TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Omit<BaseText, "text">'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Omit<BaseText, "text">'.**

I seem to sense that I should change the type of 'format', but I've tried many types and they don't work correctly.

Here is the DEMO:

```
const isFormatActive = (editor:ReactEditor, format: string) => {
  const [match] = Editor.nodes(editor, {
            match: node => node[format] === true,
            mode: "all",
  });
  return !!match;
}
```